# django default date to be in format %d-%m-%Y

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want default date but in '%d-%m-%Y' format.

models.py

```
date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

what i have tried

forms.py

```
date = forms.DateField(input_formats='%d-%m-%Y')
```

Trying the above is not giving any default date in the form.

Comment: Did you try using widgets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change default date format site wide, look at -

[DATETIME_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#date-format)

And in template, you can use a `filter` -

```
{{you_date_field|date:'%d-%m-%Y'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input formats should be a list:

`date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y'])`

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateField.input_formats)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Format` method in your **`forms.py`**:

```
date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(format='%d-%m-%Y'), 
                       input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y'])
```